# How to reshape multivariate time series data for ConvLSTM2D model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am using data having the shape `(1000, 5, 7)`. I have reshaped this to `(1000, 5, 7, 1)` to meet the need of ConvLSTM2D.
While training the model with this, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_90" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 5, 7, 1), found shape=(None, 5, 7, 1)
```

The error message is clear. However, I don't know how to reshape my data.

Here is the model I am using

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(None, 5, 7, 1), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='softmax', padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D) state, you need a 5D tensor `(samples, time, rows, cols, channels)`. Here is an example of the data shape you need:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(None, 5, 7, 1), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
samples = 1
timesteps = 1
rows = 5
cols = 7 
channels = 1
model(tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, rows, cols, channels))).shape
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have resampled my data accordingly. 
But I still get the same error while fitting the data to the model. 
`history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs= 10, batch_size= 32, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_data=(test_data, test_labels)`.
I get the same error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 5, 7, 1), found shape=(None, 5, 7, 1)`.

Comment: what is the shape of `train_data` and `train_labels`? and `test_data` and `test_labels`

Comment: Here are the shapes of my data: train_data.shape = (700, 1, 5, 7, 1), train_labels.shape = (700, 7), test_data.shape = (200, 1, 5, 7, 1), test_labels.shape = (200, 7). Labels are one hot encoded.

I am currently getting the error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 7) and (None, 1, 5, 7, 1) are incompatible`

Comment: This actually does not have anything to do with your original error and question, but see my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: That's right, it's another error message. Thanks for your support anyway.

Comment: If it's not too much request, I would like to know why we have 2 softmax. one at Conv3D layer and the other at Dense layer.

Comment: It’s a typo I forgot to remove it from the Conv3D layer

Comment: Could you kindly update the answer? It might help someone else.